# WooCommerce view all products with variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce shop that holds variable products.

I want to create some sort of export (on a page) that shows me all products including variations in a table.

I am viewing all products and created a loop to get the variations but it only shows me one product variation.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Store Management
*/
if (!is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('manage_options')) wp_die('This page is private.');
// Get
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
);
$products = get_posts( $args );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($products);
echo '</pre>';

foreach($products as $product):

    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $plan->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    ); 

    $product = wc_get_product( $product->ID );

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($variations);
    echo '</pre>';

endforeach;

?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get all variations for all products?

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't override the product variable inside the loop. Secondly, you have to check whether the product is simple or variable, because simple products will not have variants. So your code will be like this :

```
foreach($products as $product):
$product_s = wc_get_product( $product->ID );
if ($product_s->product_type == 'variable') {
    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $plan->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );
    $variations = $product_s->get_available_variations();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($variations);
    echo '</pre>';
}
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However my current problem is that it only shows one product and not the otherones... Any thoughts?

Comment: Found it. I removed the `die;` at the end so the loop wouldn't end. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I found that the `$variations` array holds another array. Should I use another loop? this is the array: `[0] => Array([attributes] => Array([attribute_pa_sizes] => smallmedium[attribute_pa_color] =>green)[image_src] =>`

Comment: and what are usage of `$args` or `$plan->ID` in your code?!

Comment: It doesn't work well, once it won't return unavailable variations

Answer (score 6):

Here is my code, to get all products and variations in WooCommerce v3+ :

```
<?php
$args = [
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'limit' => -1,
];
$all_products = wc_get_products($args);
foreach ($all_products as $key => $product) {
    echo $product->get_title();
    if ($product->get_type() == "variable") {
        foreach ($product->get_variation_attributes() as $variations) {
            foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                echo $product->get_title() . " - " . $variation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```